# PHP Array Initialization Not Working On Live Site, Compared to Local Host

Tags: php, ajax, arrays, session-variables, shopping-cart

- The issue is the results from local host are not matching up with the live site when pushed by FTP. The
  below code seems make me believe the array is not be created
  properly on the server. In addition, it is doing some funky stuff, as seen below. The error is "Cannot use a scalar value as an array" on line 97, or $_SESSION["count"][$i] +=1. Do you see the reason why? Or is there a different mistake I made?
- To summarize the code, the following session arrays make up the core of the shopping cart: $_SESSION['item_id'][$i], $_SESSION['size'][$i],
  $_SESSION['price'][$i], $_SESSION['count'][$i] ... and they all correlate to one another. Therefore a check is done to see if the combination exists, if so it appends the count, if not, adds the item combination for the first time.

### Local Host

```
In Stock: 3
Distinct Item Count: 3

Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 2 ) Item Array: 1
Array ( [0] => S [1] => M [2] => L ) Size Array: 1
Array ( [0] => 15 [1] => 20 [2] => 20 ) Price Array: 1
Array ( [0] => 15 [1] => 35 [2] => 17 ) Count Array: 1

Quantity Increased to 18 

1 
S 
15
15


2 
M 
20
35


2 
L 
20 
18 

&#124;3 ($1285)
```

### Live Site - First Add

```
In Stock: 5
0


1
M
20
1

|1 ($20)
```

### Live Site - Second Add

```
In Stock: 5
Distinct Item Count: 1

1Item Array: 1
MSize Array: 1
300Price Array: 1
1Count Array: 1


Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in /public_html/shop/helper/addtocart.php on line 97
Quantity Increased To

1
M
2


&#124;1 ($0)
```

### Code

```
    if (isset($_SESSION["item_id"]) && is_array($_SESSION["item_id"])){
        echo "Distinct Item Count: " . count($_SESSION["item_id"]);
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "Item Array: ";
        print_r($_SESSION["item_id"]);
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "Size Array: ";
        print_r($_SESSION["size"]);
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "Price Array: ";
        print_r($_SESSION["price"]);
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "Count Array: ";
        print_r($_SESSION["count"]);
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "<br/>";
    }

    //check for current product combination in visitor's shopping cart content

    //find count in cart
    if (!isset($_SESSION["item_id"])){
      $count = 0;
      }else{
        $count = count($_SESSION["item_id"]);
      }
    echo $count;
    echo "<br/>";

    if ($count == 0){

        //declare arrays
        $_SESSION["item_id"] = array();
        $_SESSION["size"] = array();
        $_SESSION["price"] = array();
        $_SESSION["count"] = array();
        $_SESSION["total"] = array();

        //add first item to cart
        $_SESSION["item_id"][] = $item_id;
        $_SESSION["size"][] = $size;
        $_SESSION["price"][] = $price;
          //fundraiser and corporate
          if (($_SESSION["acctype"] == 2 || $_SESSION["acctype"] == 3) && isset($_SESSION['userid'])){
              //update count, add 100
              $_SESSION["count"][] = 100;
              }
          else{
              $_SESSION["count"][] = 1;
          }
    }else{
        $flag=0;
        $i=0;
        while ($i <= $count){
           if( ($_SESSION["item_id"][$i] == $item_id) && ($_SESSION["size"][$i] == $size) ){
           //fundraiser and corporate
              if(!isset($_SESSION["acctype"]) || $_SESSION["acctype"] == 1){
                 //update by one
                  $_SESSION["count"][$i] +=1;
                }
              elseif(isset($_SESSION['userid']) && ($_SESSION["acctype"] == 2 || $_SESSION["acctype"] == 3)){
                    //update count, add 100
                    $_SESSION["count"][$i] +=100;
                }
              else{
                  echo "Hmm";
                }
              //update cart stats
              echo notify('Quantity Increased To' . ' ' . $_SESSION["count"][$i]);
              //was there combination match?
              $flag = 1;
              }
        $i++;
        }
        if($flag == 0){
                  $_SESSION["item_id"][] = $item_id;
                  $_SESSION["size"][] = $size;
                  $_SESSION["price"][] = $price;
                    //fundraiser and corporate
                    if (($_SESSION["acctype"] == 2 || $_SESSION["acctype"] == 3) && isset($_SESSION['userid'])){
                        //update count, add 100
                        $_SESSION["count"][] = 100;
                    }else{
                    $_SESSION["count"][] = 1;
                    }
         }
    }
```

Comment: What kind of answer do you expect to get?

Comment: What is the error you are receiving?  Debugging is hard when the error is unknown.

Comment: I am looking to get an answer on the error or solution..I reformatting the above text, so you can see I was expecting the live site to match the local site. The error: Cannot use a scalar value as an array ..yet the arrays are defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:** Check to see if [register_globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) is enabled on your live server using `var_dump(ini_get('register_globals'))` or `phpinfo()` . If register_globals is enabled, the preferable solution is to disable register globals—it leads to security problems and as of PHP 5.3 is deprecated.

**Longer answer:** 'Cannot use a scalar value as an array' means that a scalar value (e.g. number) exists in the variable that you are referencing as an array. I do not see anywhere that you assign a scalar directly to `$_SESSION["count"]`.

However, if [register_globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) is enabled `$count` would become a reference to `$_SESSION["count"]`, which means `$count = 0` would be setting `$_SESSION["count"]` to a scalar. Again, the preferable solution would be to disable register_globals, but a workaround would be to rename the `$count` variable to something else.

Comment: I thought I compared the php setting for both the local and live server, but you were 100% correct. The register_globals was ON. I changed it to OFF, and the local and live server are both working the same. Thanks so much. As you said, OFF is the preferable configuration, correct?

Comment: @chsnmyrhoades: Yes, OFF is very much preferable. See the [PHP documentation on register_globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) to see examples of why it is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't look at your code but I had a similar issue and it was my FTP client, somehow along the transfer it was changing only some of the text causing errors like you have shown above.

I stopped using FileZilla and started using CyberDuck and everything was good, inspect the code on your server and verify if it has been changed at all.

Comment: I double checked the live site again and the code does match. Thanks for the suggestion.